# How can I print a dictionary key while in a for loop in python

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a problem, I have a dictionary and i need to pass a function to each value of the dictionary, I need my output to include the value key + the result of the function.
The program itself should identify open reading frames in a given DNA sequences, I have this part working but i need to print the name of sequence + the open reading frames.

Im new to programming and i got stuck. All help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#converts a fasta file into a dictionary.

import re

myfile = input("Enter a file name and directory:")
try:
    f=open(myfile)
except IOError:
    print("File doesn't exist!")

seqs = {}
for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip()
#Gets rid of triling empy spaces.

    if line[0]=='>':
        words=line.split()
        name=words[0][1:]
        seqs[name] = ''
    else:
        seqs[name] = seqs[name] + line
print("Number of entries:",len(seqs.keys()))
length_seqs = {key:len(seq)for key, seq in seqs.items()}

sorted_length_seqs = sorted(length_seqs.items(), key=lambda kv:kv[1])
print("Entries by length:",sorted_length_seqs)

#finds the ORF in the dictionary sequences.
def find_ORFs(DNA):
    ORFs = []
    if 'ATG' in DNA:
        for startMatch in re.finditer('ATG',DNA):
            remaining = DNA[startMatch.start():]
            for stopMatch in re.finditer('TAA|TGA|TAG',remaining):
                substring = remaining[:stopMatch.end()]
                if len(substring) % 3 == 0:
                    ORFs.append(substring)
                    break
    else:
        print("There are no ORFs in your sequence")
    ORFs.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    print(ORFs)
    for ORF in ORFs:
        print(ORF,'ORF lenght',len(ORF))

#passes the function to the dictionary values.
#Here i need to pass the function to each of the values of the dictionary but i cant manage to make it print the the dictionary key of each value.

for seq in seqs:
    DNA = seqs[seq]
    ORF = find_ORFs(DNA)
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to address your problem (the code you posted contains a lot of information that is not connected to your problem at all)!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the name of the sequence to the function as well:

```py
def find_ORFs(name, DNA):
    ORFs = []
    if 'ATG' in DNA:
        for startMatch in re.finditer('ATG',DNA):
            remaining = DNA[startMatch.start():]
            for stopMatch in re.finditer('TAA|TGA|TAG',remaining):
                substring = remaining[:stopMatch.end()]
                if len(substring) % 3 == 0:
                    ORFs.append(substring)
                    break
    else:
        print("There are no ORFs in your sequence: {}".format(name))
    ORFs.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    print(ORFs)
    for ORF in ORFs:
        print("{}, {}, {}".format(name, len(ORF), ORF))

for name, DNA in seqs.items():
    ORF = find_ORFs(name, DNA)
```

---

You should also take a look at some external libraries that can help you with parsing FASTA files, such as [SeqIO from BioPython](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO).

Comment: Thank you for your help I will give it a try